# Changing "new item" link results in inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list where I'm trying to modify the "+ new item" link at the top to point to a different form than the default for that list. (I realize I can change the default content type but that's not what I want to do .)

I'm using jQuery and my script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("href", ".../_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Sandbox/NewForm.aspx?Source=.../Lists/Sandbox/AllItems.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x01080013D954563B0D1441BC90FAEC292D8798&RootFolder=/Lists/Sandbox");
    $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("onclick", "");
});
```

(please ignore the "...")

I've gone in and edited the main web part on AllItems.aspx and added jQuery and my script into the JS link box, and it works when you initially click on the link to the list in the left-hand navigation, then click + new item. (I get the correct form.)

The problem is that after I've created a new item and it returns me to the list view, when I click + new item again, it sends me to the default content type instead of the one I want it to direct me to. Refreshing seems to fix it, but it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because an async postback is occuring, which refreshes the Add New link back to the original value.

To hook into the "after async" event, try the following:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function(){
    //TODO: rebind your jquery here
});
```

[Sys.Application.add_load event details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx)

EDIT:
So the following does not work? Add a console.log to see if/when it fires.

```
$(document).ready(bindLink);

Sys.Application.add_load(bindLink);

function bindLink() {
     $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("href", ".../_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Sandbox/NewForm.aspx?Source=.../Lists/Sandbox/AllItems.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x01080013D954563B0D1441BC90FAEC292D8798&RootFolder=/Lists/Sandbox");
     $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("onclick", "");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.

Comment: "(bindLink)"? Will I run into problems if I'm using jQuery 3.x? (I read bind has been deprecated.)

Comment: bindLink is just the name I gave the custom function, call it "setLinkToContentType" if you want ;) . I chose to extract the function since the binding logic is the same for both jquery and the "add_load" event.

Comment: Gotcha. Sadly this too didn't do the trick. Still reverts back to the original link after saving a list item. Refreshing goes back to my customization.

Comment: Correction: This works consistently after clearing my cache. =P

Comment: Ah yes, that pesky cache. I tend to open Chrome dev tools and check the "Disable cache" option under the Network tab whenever I'm making js/html/css changes to anything. Anyways, glad it helped! :)